# PHP is being updated from version 5.5 to 5.6

Tags: wordpress, php

My host is upgrading php from version 5.5 to 5.6 next week.  I am running wordpress v 4.5.3 and civicrm v 4.7.10.  Should I be concerned about anything going wrong with the running of my site after the upgrade?  They offer a 'PHP CGI' installer that can be used to install an older version of PHP onto my site if needed.

I'm a bit of a newbie so sorry for my ignorance on this matter.

Pete

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM runs great on PHP 5.6 - better than it does on PHP 5.5!  I make that upgrade regularly without thinking - assuming CiviCRM is up-to-date, which in your case it is.

Note that upgrading to PHP 7 is not yet supported, though it will be imminently.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to ensure SMTP will work properly. Bad certificates will cause mail not to send and the "CRON not Running" Error.
Go to the following website:
http://www.checktls.com/

and enter you email address and press the CheckTLS button and review the output.

In my case, it highlighted that the mail server was using expired and self-signed certificates.